# pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction vs pcl::Kmeans

Tags: c++, c++14, cluster-analysis, k-means, point-cloud-library

In the PCL tutorial, we can learn how to segment a plane and extract the Euclidean cluster point clouds. So now, after I used the `pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction` algorithm. I need the centroid or the mean position of each cluster.

Using `pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction` I need to calculate the centroid with the for loops. After my search I found out the `pcl::Kmeans` which provides directly a function `get_centroids()` to get the centroids of the clusters: https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_kmeans.html#a8788bd4098ea370e018119fc516a5eb4

Now, I'm a little bit confused. What is the real application different between `pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction` and `pcl::Kmeans`? After analysing the source code, `pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction` provides us clusters based on three parameters. `pcl::Kmeans` is used if we determine how many clusters we want to generate, because of the arguments in the constructor `Kmeans (unsigned int num_points, unsigned int num_dimensions)`.

Is that true? Is there any other cases?

Comment: you can use [pcl::computeCentroid()]( https://pointclouds.org/documentation/group__common.html#ga9e10574ff42edc90e7dd583a36e94ce6) to calculate the centroid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two very different algorithms:

1. [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) iteratively finds spherical clusters of points (usually high-dimensional), where cluster affinity is based on a distance to the cluster center. From a math point of view: it chooses centroids that will minimize the squared distances of cluster points to the centroid - and as mentioned, each points belongs to the cluster with the nearest centroid.
2. [cluster_extraction](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cluster_extraction.html) is a greedy region growing algorithm based on nearest neighbors. Cluster affinity is based on a distance to any point of a cluster (cluster tolerance parameter).

**cluster extraction** with tolerance larger than distance among blue/black dots, but smaller than distance between black and blue dots:
[image: cluster extraction - with tolerance larger than distance among blue/black dots, but smaller than distance between black and blue dots]

**k-means** with k=2
[image: k-means with k=2]

Comment: Awesome answer Mark! Short, clear and with pictures that help a lot.